# MySQL using result of first query in second query

Tags: php, mysql

Is this possible. I have a MySQL query that returns a dynamic number of rows.

What I want to do is use the result from the returned rows as the column names in another query.

Example:

Result from first query:
SeqID4901
SeqID4902
SeqID4903

Normal second query:

```
mysql_select_db($database_Hp, $conn);
$query_Lookup_Hist = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Hist WHERE HeadID = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Hist, "text"));
$Lookup_Hist  = mysql_query($query_Lookup_Hist , $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Lookup_Hist  = mysql_fetch_assoc($Lookup_Hist );
```

Using result of first query

```
mysql_select_db($database_Hp, $conn);
$query_Lookup_Hist = sprintf("SELECT SeqID4901, SeqID4902, SeqID4903 FROM Hist WHERE HeadID = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_Hist, "text"));
$Lookup_Hist  = mysql_query($query_Lookup_Hist , $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Lookup_Hist  = mysql_fetch_assoc($Lookup_Hist );
```

As I say, is this possible and where would I start.

Many trhanks in advance for your time.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Using `sprintf` to escape is extremely error prone as well. Prepared statements with placeholder values are far more secure.

Comment: If we were to delete all the mysql_* content on this site, we might see a lot less of this

Comment: @Drew, Hi what is your meaning "
 
If we were to delete all the mysql_* content on this site, we might see a lot less of this"

Comment: Like, did you read what @tadman wrote?

Comment: @Drew, I did and have taken his comments on board and I will look into it. As for now, I have what I have. It's very easy to criticise how others work, it;s a lot harder to provide constructive help.

Comment: Well then why don't you go look at my last 10 to 20 answers. I have 800 answers on this site. You have 4.

Comment: @Drew, very helpful, I think not. I use this great forum for technical help not to be told yours is bigger than mine. Can you help with my question or not. If you can't thats ok by me. Again, thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: We just gave you that info. Get off of `mysql_` and get on to `PDO`

Comment: @Drew, As I thought, many thanks.

Comment: @DCJones We're just looking out for you here. `mysql_query` is **toast**, it's been deleted from PHP. This code will need to be updated, it's already obsolete, so it's in your best interest to do it properly now by using a tool like PDO, if not something better.

Comment: @tadman, I am active in moving to using PDO. I am still learning and I know most forum users want and do help which is very much appriciated by guys like myself. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want make this using just one query:

```
$columns = array();
$query = mysql_query("select column_with_column_names from your_table");
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    $columns [] = $res['model'];

$result  = mysql_query("SELECT ".implode(",",$columns)." FROM your_other_table");
```

Comment: That's a pretty messy way of doing it. Why not with a subquery?

Comment: @Arivan Bastos, Thank you very much, perfect. P.S. I will be moving over to using PDO within the next 4 months.